# JOOQ or alternatives for code reduction in generated classes

Tags: database, code-generation, jooq

For a bigger project, for example 100+ tables, size of the code (therefore classes and functions needed/not needed) is critical. Here comes my question: what is the best way to reduce code as much as possible when using JOOQ for class generation or are there any alternatives of generating them as efficient as possible?
I know one option is the include/exclude such as:

```
 <excludes>
     TABLE
     |DATA.*
 </excludes>
```

This reduces automatically the code by eliminating unneeded tables/routines/etc.
Are there any other possibilities or better solution to do so? Is that it? Better said, can I reduce the code even more?

Comment: What do you want to reduce, specifically, and why exactly?

Comment: @CraciunAndreea -  Why?  (genuinely curious)

Comment: I sincerely do not understand this request. Why does every extra line count? I mean, do generated Javadoc count, too? This "optimisation" simply hasn't been a use-case for anyone so far. In that case, you'll probably have to roll your own code generator. Or you write the generated classes manually. You can take inspiration from jOOQ's `JavaGenerator`...

Comment: I think you answered my question now. That I need to write on my own for more. I was expecting it because I read carefully the documentation and what I can do with JOOQ, but I was not 100% sure. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, I'll provide that comment as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, I take that you are really keen on avoiding pretty much every line of code that you deem unnecessary, perhaps even including generated Javadoc.

This has not been a popular use case for any jOOQ user so far, which is why there aren't many means of achieving what you want through out of the box functionality. As you've already discovered, you can reduce the number of objects (e.g. tables) being included, as well as the object types (e.g. tables, procedures, sequences, etc.), but you cannot really influence the layout of generated code yet in jOOQ 3.x.

This means you'll have to roll your own. Either:

- Implement your own code generator, taking inspiration from the `JavaGenerator`
- Write the "generated" classes manually, taking inspiration from the `JavaGenerator`'s output